# C# JSON - Serialization of multiple objects of different types, that have the same properties

Tags: c#, json

I have used JSON serialization quite a bit, but have come across a scenario (That I have not encountered before) in which I have an object that can contain any number of similar objects, with the same properties. For example

```
{
"Objects": {
   "ObjectA": {
     "prop1": 6601,
     "prop2": "Prop",
     "propParams": [
       {
         "Type": 0,
         "Name": "name"
       }
     ]
  },
  "ObjectB ": {
    "prop1": 6601,
    "prop2": "Prop",
    "propParams": []
    }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately it is not a list/array of objects. Which is one of my issues.

So I have a few things that I could use some help, suggestions, guidance, etc..
on on how to deal with them.

I feel I should start with the objects in `Objects` first. As you can see, they are of different types, but contain the same properties, and this will hold true for any object in this `Objects` class. Is there a way to take an object and "Convert" it to a `Standard` object, so long it contains the appropriate properties?  I am thinking something with JsonConvert.  Maybe with the Object Type as a string property of the "Standard" object.

2nd is there a way to make the objects in `Objects` to an array/list regardless of its object type?  I understand this may have to done first, but it made sense to ask in the order I did.

I am currently scouring the web for any other help, but figured I would ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Objects` should be treated as a `Dictionary<string, Standard>`.

For example, this LINQPad query:

```
void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(@"{
    ""Objects"": {
       ""ObjectA"": {
         ""prop1"": 6601,
         ""prop2"": ""Prop"",
         ""propParams"": [
           {
             ""Type"": 0,
             ""Name"": ""name""
           }
         ]
      },
      ""ObjectB "": {
        ""prop1"": 6601,
        ""prop2"": ""Prop"",
        ""propParams"": []
        }
       }
    }").Dump();
}

public class Payload
{
    public Dictionary<string, Standard> Objects{get;set;}
}

public class Standard
{
    public int Prop1{get;set;}
    public string Prop2{get;set;}
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> PropParams{get;set;}
}
```

Will yield this result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I never really knew that, I will give that a try.